# Jssor - reduce slides on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, jssor

I am working on a full-width slider with 1 to X slides, displaying 4 slides at a time. It looks really great on large or medium screens, but the responsive script will decrease the width of the slider on smaller screens drastically to still contain all 4 slides. Is there a way to adjust the Cols or SlideWidth only on smaller screens so it won't resize the slides so drastically?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jssor_1_options = {
        $AutoPlay: true,
        $AutoPlaySteps: 4,
        $FillMode: 5,
        $Cols: 4,
        $SlideWidth: 313,
        $SlideSpacing: 15,
        $SlideDuration: 800,
        $SlideEasing: $Jease$.$OutQuint,
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
            $Steps: 1,
        },
    };

    var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

    function ScaleSlider() {
        var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if (refSize) {
            refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1920);
            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
    }

    ScaleSlider();
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
});
```

Comment: reduce $Cols depending on the screen.width

Comment: How am I supposed to reinitialize jssor with a different configuration depending on screen width, without reducing the performance of the site?

Comment: depending on screen width, load var jssor_1_options with different values for $Cols

Comment: But this is a one-time-check, isn't it? When someone is browsing with only the half-width of his browser after resizing it, he would need to reload the page first.

Comment: check for device(screen) width, not window width